# Issue with jQuery addClass to input text box

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to apply a simple class to an input text box, but oddly it is not working.

```js
$('body, :text').addClass('courier');
$('body, input[type=text]').addClass('courier');
$('body, #text').addClass('courier');
```

```css
.courier {
      font-family: Courier New, serif;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

I tried these three methods, but the changes are applied only to the body. I just also tried to add the class just to the input text.

```
$('body, :text').addClass('courier');
$('body, input[type=text]').addClass('courier');
$('body, #text').addClass('courier');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The code you've posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7t344/ Something else must be going on.  Please provide an example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you using multiple instances of `id="text"`?

Answer (score 3):

you should write

```
$('body input[type=text]').addClass('courier');
```

or

```
$('input[type=text]').addClass('courier');
```

you can see it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/JmHpC/)

Comment: i added a fiddle to demonstrate the code in action, you probably need to rap your code in the `jQuery` function or `$(document).ready();`

Comment: Well, I did some tests with the suggested code and I'm seeing the problem is not with the addClass. Sorry about the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since your element already has an ID...  use that for reference...

This should be the simplest way to add a class to your input:

```
$('#text').addClass('courier');
```